# How can I mock up a repository method that is being used inside the Method to test (in the model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, moq, xunit

I am trying to get this use case work for me:

I am having a Repository class: `ABCRepository`
which is having a virtual method `GetMyValues()`

A Model Class: `ABCModel`, having a method `ABCToTest()`. 
Inside this `ABCToTest()`, I am trying to access `ABCRepository` using [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject):

```
  var repo =  kernel.Get<ABCRepository>();

    //further using repository method

    var results =  repo.GetMyValues();
```

Now, I am using following code to create Unittest for ABCToTest() and mocking GetMyValues() method:

```
            var kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();

            kernel.Bind<ABCRepository>().ToMock();


            kernel.Bind<ABCModel>().ToMock();

            var abcRepo= kernel.GetMock<ABCRepository>();



            abcRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetMyValues()).Returns("ABC");

//This is a static method I am using to initialize the kernel object, ABCToTest() method is using.
            MvcApplication.InitializeInjection(kernel);

            var model= kernel.GetMock<ABCModel>().Object;

            model.ABCToTest("177737");
```

When I am trying to DEBUG/Run the Test, I can see, the `GetMyValues()` method call inside `ABCTotTest` is not  returning "ABC" but `NULL`.

What's wrong I am doing with this implementation? Any suggestions and pointers are highly appreciated..

Thanks & Regards
sumeet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've stumbled across the service locator anti-pattern (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

You should change your ABCModel class so you inject an ABCRepository into the constructor:

```
private readonly IABCRepository repo;

public ABCModel(IABCRepository repo)
{
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

Then your unit test will look like this:

```
private Mock<IABCRepository> mockRepo;
private ABCModel model;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    mockRepo = new Mock<IABCRepository>();

    model = new ABCModel(mockRepo.Object);
}    

[Test]
public void ABCToTest_WhenCalled_CallsRepository
{       
    model.ABCToTest("177737");

    mockRepo.Verify(a => a.GetMyValues(), Times.Once);
}
```